# what does the following "$?run" mean in shell csh

Tags: linux, csh

What `$?run` does in the following example? `run` is variation with `run` directory. I understand that `$?` has the status of the last command.

```
if ( ! $?run ) then  
  set run = $PWD
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$?var_name` to check if a variable is defined. From `man csh`:

```
   $?name
   ${?name}
           Substitutes the string `1' if name is set, `0' if it is not.
```

This is **not** the same as the special `$?` variable (yeah, the syntax is a bit confusing).